# setTypefacemethod

Tags: android, android-widget, multilingual

Can I use setTypeface method for android spinner elements?
I cannot set typeface for my spinner elements

```
Rainfall=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.rainfall);
gcd = new Geocoder(this,Locale.getDefault());
ArrayList<String>rain=new ArrayList<String>();
rain.add("<50");
rain.add("50-100");
rain.add("100-125");
rain.add("125-150");
rain.add("150-200");
rain.add(">200");
```

Please Help

Please answer...

Answer (score 0):

You call `setTypeface()` on the `TextView` created by your `SpinnerAdapter` (e.g., in `getView()`).